# Every action gives rise to a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions, group-homomorphism

I'm reading Chapter 3 from the book "The theory of finite groups" by Kurzweil and Stellmacher where they say the following:

Let $G$ act on a set $\Omega$. That is, for each $x\in G$ and $\alpha\in\Omega$, there exists an element $\alpha^x\in \Omega$ which satisfies $\alpha^1=\alpha$ and $\alpha^{xy}=(\alpha^x)^y$.

Define the mapping $\pi:G\to S_{\Omega}$ as $\pi(x)=x^\pi$ where $x^\pi: \alpha\mapsto \alpha^x$. Then $\pi$ is a homomorphism.

I'm having trouble justifying this claim because I'm only able to show that $\pi(xy)=\pi(y)\pi(x)$.

**My attempt:** Since
$$\begin{align}
(xy)^\pi(\alpha)&=\alpha^{xy}\\
&=(\alpha^x)^y\\
&=y^\pi(\alpha^x)\\
&=y^\pi(x^{\pi}(\alpha)),
\end{align}$$
so $$\pi(xy)=\pi(y)\pi(x).$$

> Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How come $$(xy)^\pi=(\alpha)(xy)^{\alpha}?$$

Comment: @Shaun Oops, the $=$ was misplaced.

Comment: What is $$(xy)^\alpha?$$

Comment: @Shaun My bad, fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, right actions and writing functions on the left gives you a parity issue.  You can either write your functions on the right (which is super weird, my brain will never be comfortable with $(x)f$), or you can work with left actions, or you can throw an inverse in there, i.e., define $\pi$ by $x^\pi\colon\alpha \mapsto \alpha^{x^{-1}}$.

Not having read that particular book I'm not sure which of these three solutions the authors had in mind.

**Edit:** As you've said that the book writes functions as $x^f$, that means they're evaluating functions from left to right.  So in the composition $fg$ the function $f$ is evaluated first: $x^{fg} = (x^f)^g$.  Note this is backwards in order to how we normally write functions as evaluating from right to left: $(fg)(x) = f(g(x))$.  Getting that order wrong is why you are getting an anti-automorphism.

So the solution is you should write your functions on the right.  That means you need to prove that $(\alpha)(xy)^\pi = ((\alpha)x^\pi)y^\pi$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my question. With the way things are written in the book, I get an anti-homomorphism and not a homomorphism. I want to understand what the book means.

Comment: Does the book write their functions on the right elsewhere?  Does the book uses left actions elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, the book always writes the functions as $x^f$ (but how does that make a difference?). I don't know what right/left action means here. In the book, the action is always written as $(\alpha,g)\mapsto \alpha^g$.

Comment: I've edited my answer, the authors intend for you to write your functions on the right instead of the left, and as you've seen it does actually matter what side they're on because it affects how function composition is defined.

Comment: So basically, it $(\alpha^x)^y=\pi(y)(\alpha^x)=\pi(x)\pi(y)(\alpha)$ is how the proof should end?

Comment: No, you should write the functions on the right instead of the left.